# Why can't I convert from 'System.IO.StreamWriter' to 'CsvHelper.ISerializer'?

Tags: c#, .net-core, csvhelper

Trying to write the contents of people to a CSVfile and then export it, however I am getting a build error and its failing. the error is:

`cannot convert from 'System.IO.StreamWriter' to 'CsvHelper.ISerializer'`

Not sure why this is happening unless as I am certain I have done it this way loads of times.

```
private void ExportAsCSV()
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(people);
            }

            var arr = memoryStream.ToArray();
            js.SaveAs("people.csv",arr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This suggests `CsvHelper.CsvWriter(TextWriter)` is not in scope. Double check that you're getting the right version of the package, and that `StreamWriter` is the usual class (`System.IO.StreamWriter`). Use "Go to Definition" on `CsvWriter` to double-check.

Comment: @JeroenMostert did you mean to check csvWriter? i did and its belongs to the CSVhelper class which uses using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using CsvHelper.TypeConversion;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

Comment: Yes, but what the compiler is telling you is that it is invoking the `CsvWriter` constructor that takes an `ISerializer`, and failing since there's no conversion. It should have picked the `CsvWriter` constructor that takes a `TextWriter`, since `StreamWriter` inherits from that, so either that constructor is missing (for whatever reason) or the compiler's overload resolution is broken (a little less probable, but weirder things have happened).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

There was a breaking change with version 13.0.0.  There have been many issues with localization, so @JoshClose is requiring users to specify the `CultureInfo` they want to use.  You now need to include `CultureInfo` when creating `CsvReader` and `CsvWriter`.  https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1441

```cs
private void ExportAsCSV()
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(people);
            }

            var arr = memoryStream.ToArray();
            js.SaveAs("people.csv",arr);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` was the default in previous versions.

Consider

- `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` - If you control both the writing and the reading of the file. That way it will work no matter what culture the user has on his computer.
- `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")` - If you need it to work for a [particular culture](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e1BX7M), independent of the user's culture.

Comment: you saved me a lot of time, thanks, David
*works for v15.0.0